# Creating an Arch ISO image produces invalid cross-device link errors

Tags: arch-linux, mount, iso, hard-link

I have been trying to create a custom Arch ISO by following the [archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) article at *The ArchWiki*, unfortunately whenever I run `./build.sh -v` from my `~/archlive` directory I get one of two types of error. Here is one such type of error:

```
[mkarchiso] INFO: Installing packages to 'work/i686/airootfs/'...
==> Creating install root at work/i686/airootfs
mount: udev is already mounted or /root/archlive/work/i686/airootfs/dev busy
       udev is already mounted on /root/archlive/work/i686/airootfs/dev
       udev is already mounted on /root/archlive/work/i686/airootfs/dev
==> ERROR: failed to setup chroot work/i686/airootfs
```

To solve this problem I run `umount /root/archlive/work/i686/airootfs/dev` but this does not always work (in the case of it 'not working' it returns the exact same error when I re-run `./build.sh -v`). Alternatively sometimes running `./build.sh -v` returns thousands of lines of the form:

```
cp: cannot create hard link 'work/airootfs/sbin' to 'work/i686/airootfs/sbin': Invalid cross-device link
```

(where the `i686` and `sbin` of this output varies amongst the thousands of line of output). I initially thought that these errors might be because of my custom modifications to `~/archlive` (if you want some specifics [here](https://github.com/fusion809/archiso) is my GitHub repo containing `~/archlive` and `~/customrepo` (where I have my custom local pacman repo)), but I then created a fresh `~/archlive2` directory of the `releng` archiso profile via running:

```
cp -r /usr/share/archiso/configs/releng/* ~/archlive2
```

and I got the same errors from running `./build.sh -v` in this new directory.

If relevant here is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# UUID=7d1abebf-09fa-4734-9843-c8d901f1c8ad
/dev/sdb1               /               ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 1
```

(I am guessing it might be based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108558/27613) answer)