# On xfs, why can't I hardlink to /tmp/, giving the error "Invalid cross-device link" when my fstab indicates tmp is on the same partition?

Tags: filesystems, hard-link, xfs, tmp, ln

My error:

```
ln "99700.fa821246f01ef7f3d86a503e33de5753b50640d69de790fd3db5a5dc31ffa45d1dc64a93f950379ee432aa27cbb0593e6e50ddbb6f8a7e279afaf90cec961233.png" /home/anon/foo.png         
# ^ works fine ^

ln "99700.fa821246f01ef7f3d86a503e33de5753b50640d69de790fd3db5a5dc31ffa45d1dc64a93f950379ee432aa27cbb0593e6e50ddbb6f8a7e279afaf90cec961233.png" /tmp/foo.png  
ln: failed to create hard link '/tmp/foo.png' => '99700.fa821246f01ef7f3d86a503e33de5753b50640d69de790fd3db5a5dc31ffa45d1dc64a93f950379ee432aa27cbb0593e6e50ddbb6f8a7e279afaf90cec961233.png': Invalid cross-device link
```

This answer here states: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108558/79280

> it's most likely that your /home directory isn't on the same partition as the /root directory.

> You can easily check this with cat /etc/fstab hardlinks cannot be created between different partitions, only symlinks can.

However as you can see:

```
cat /etc/fstab                                                                                                                                                                                      1 ✘ 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=A189-F750                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=11bc9e0c-1727-4df7-b357-0fc11f66444a swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=acc6e22f-a4d8-4766-bf57-ae13838bd5a8 /              xfs     defaults,noatime 0 1
```

This indicates that `/tmp/` and `/home/` should be on the mount point. Is this perhaps a bug, or does `/tmp/` have special behaviour here that I am not aware of?

Also; is this specific to xfs? I don't have a machine to test this on for ext4.

---

### Edit:

Using the recommended commands from the comments.

```
cat /proc/self/mountinfo                                                                                                                                                                            1 ✘ 
24 29 0:22 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:5 - proc proc rw
25 29 0:23 / /sys rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:6 - sysfs sys rw
26 29 0:5 / /dev rw,nosuid,relatime shared:2 - devtmpfs dev rw,size=8009848k,nr_inodes=2002462,mode=755,inode64
27 29 0:24 / /run rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime shared:12 - tmpfs run rw,mode=755,inode64
28 25 0:25 / /sys/firmware/efi/efivars rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:7 - efivarfs efivarfs rw
29 1 259:3 / / rw,noatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/nvme0n1p3 rw,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
30 25 0:6 / /sys/kernel/security rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:8 - securityfs securityfs rw
31 26 0:26 / /dev/shm rw,nosuid,nodev shared:3 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,inode64
32 26 0:27 / /dev/pts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime shared:4 - devpts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
33 25 0:28 / /sys/fs/cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:9 - cgroup2 cgroup2 rw,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot
34 25 0:29 / /sys/fs/pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:10 - pstore pstore rw
35 25 0:30 / /sys/fs/bpf rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:11 - bpf none rw,mode=700
36 24 0:31 / /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc rw,relatime shared:13 - autofs systemd-1 rw,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1148
37 26 0:21 / /dev/mqueue rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:14 - mqueue mqueue rw
38 26 0:32 / /dev/hugepages rw,relatime shared:15 - hugetlbfs hugetlbfs rw,pagesize=2M
39 25 0:7 / /sys/kernel/debug rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:16 - debugfs debugfs rw
40 25 0:11 / /sys/kernel/tracing rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:17 - tracefs tracefs rw
41 25 0:33 / /sys/kernel/config rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:18 - configfs configfs rw
42 36 0:34 / /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:19 - binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw
44 25 0:35 / /sys/fs/fuse/connections rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:20 - fusectl fusectl rw
142 29 0:37 / /tmp rw,nosuid,nodev shared:63 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=8019684k,nr_inodes=409600,inode64
149 29 259:1 / /boot/efi rw,relatime shared:77 - vfat /dev/nvme0n1p1 rw,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro
445 27 0:43 / /run/user/1000 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime shared:242 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=1603936k,nr_inodes=400984,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1001,inode64
514 445 0:45 / /run/user/1000/gvfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime shared:278 - fuse.gvfsd-fuse gvfsd-fuse rw,user_id=1000,group_id=1001
531 445 0:46 / /run/user/1000/doc rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime shared:297 - fuse.portal portal rw,user_id=1000,group_id=1001
```

and

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8009848k,nr_inodes=2002462,mode=755,inode64)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on / type xfs (rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1148)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=8019684k,nr_inodes=409600,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1603936k,nr_inodes=400984,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1001,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1001)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1001)
```

Comment: No, `cat /etc/fstab` does not "prove" anything at all. Show the output of `cat /proc/self/mountinfo` instead

Comment: Your `/etc/fstab` only shows the mounts that are automatically made, always. You could well have _other_ volumes mounted later.  What does the `mount` command with no options output?

Comment: @UncleBilly Thanks, and I updated the question with that command. I can't quite parse it though.

Comment: It's easy -- you have mounted tmpfs (a virtual file system) on `/tmp` -- the fifth line from the end. FWIW, the format of the `mountinfo` file is described in `man 5 proc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data indicates that `/tmp` is a separate filesystem (tmpfs):

```
142 29 0:37 / /tmp rw,nosuid,nodev shared:63 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,size=8019684k,nr_inodes=409600,inode64
```

You can disable this behaviour by:

```
sudo systemctl mask tmp.mount
```

In which case `/tmp` will belong to your root filesystem. You'll have to reboot.

Comment: Very interesting. I am going to have to figure out how to check if a path is on the same filesystem as the source, for my api.

Comment: @Anon A `stat` call would do that. The call would return a device number.